# How to perform custom sort in python on dictionary with custom class keys?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-2.6

I need to sort a dictionary returned by [pysphere's](https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/) `VIServer.get_datastore`. It should be sorted by free space on the datastore which we can get by :

```
from pysphere import VIServer, VIProperty
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = VIServer()
    print "Connecting to vSphere..."
    server.connect(VSPHERE_IP, VSPHERE_USER, VSPHERE_PASS)
    datastores = server.get_datastores()
    for ds, name in datastores.iteritems():
        props = VIProperty(server, ds)
        freeSpace = props.summary.freeSpace
```

I know I can use [sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[, reverse]]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and create a custom sort function but I do not know which type will there be as an argument to this function.

I can't use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) because I am bound to python 2.6 (don't ask why :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform the lookup for free space in your key function:

```
server = VIServer()
server.connect(VSPHERE_IP, VSPHERE_USER, VSPHERE_PASS)
datastores = server.get_datastores()

ds_keys = sorted(datastores,
                 key=lambda ds: VIProperty(server, ds).summary.freeSpace
                 reverse=True)
```

This produces a sorted list of the *keys* from `datastores`; you can use that to iterate in a specific order. I presumed you wanted the datastore with the most space free listed first.

You can get sorted key-value pairs too, replace `ds` with `item` and `item[0]`, respectively:

```
ds_items = sorted(datastores.items(),
                  key=lambda item: VIProperty(server, item[0]).summary.freeSpace
                  reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this version works. Can you explain where should I put this item to get key-value pairs?

Comment: Ahh... It was necessary to add `.items()` ( `iteritems()` ). Now it's perfect:) Thanks.

Comment: @Patryk: there is little point in using `dict.iteritems()` here as `sorted()` will put those items into a list anyway.